# sql query to get the max date for a particular element

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table

PEEVF

| EFFECTIVE_START_DATE | EFFECTIVE_END_DATE | PERSON_ID | ELEMENT_NAME | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-JAN-2021 | 10-JAN-2021 | 19 | Bonus | 9.1 |
| 11-JAN-2021 | 28-MAR-2021 | 19 | Bonus | 11 |
| 29-MAR-2021 | 10-APR-2021 | 19 | Bonus | 11.1 |
| 11-APR-2021 | 31-DEC-2021 | 19 | Bonus | 10 |
| 11-APR-2022 | 30-APR-2022 | 19 | Bonus | 12 |
| 19-APR-2022 | 30-MAY-2022 | 19 | LTP | 09 |
| 01-JAN-2019 | 30-APR-2019 | 8 | Bonus | 5 |
| 11-MAR-2021 | 10-JAN-2021 | 10 | Bonus | 11 |
| 11-JAN-2021 | 28-MAR-2021 | 10 | Bonus | 11.1 |
| 20-JAN-2019 | 08-MAR-2019 | 1 | LTP | 9 |
| 11-APR-2019 | 19-AUG-2019 | 1 | LTP | 9.8 |

I want to display the following output by using `MAX`and not use `ROW_NUM`.

| LATEST_EFF_DT_BONUS | LATEST_EFF_DT_LTP | BONUS_VAL | LTP_VAL | PERSON_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11-APR-2022 |  | 12 |  | 19 |
|  | 19-APR-2022 |  | 09 | 19 |
| 01-JAN-2019 |  | 5 |  | 8 |
| 11-JAN-2021 |  | 11.1 |  | 10 |
|  | 11-APR-2019 |  | 9.8 | 1 |

When i am using the below statement, it is not giving correct value.

```
max(effective_start_Date)  over ( PARTITION BY ELEMENT_NAME,EFFECTIVE_START_DATE order by PERSON_ID )
```

Comment: `MAX(effective_start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ... effective_start_date`? You are asking for the maximum start date per start date? That is of course the start date itself. Are you looking for `PARTITION BY person_id, element_name` maybe?

Comment: It's unclear what you want. The rows with the maximum dates, or the rows with the maximum values.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Based on the downvote, I revised SQL. Now SQL returns the desired result.

### SQL:

```
with b as (
  select
    person_id,
    element_name,
    max(effective_end_date) as msd
  from peevf 
  group by person_id, element_name
) select
 case when b.element_name = 'Bonus' then to_char(a.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') else ' ' end  as LATEST_EFF_DT_BONUS,
 case when b.element_name = 'LTP' then to_char(a.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') else ' ' end as LATEST_EFF_DT_LTP,
 case when b.element_name = 'Bonus' then trim(trailing '.' from to_char(a.value,'fm99D9')) else ' ' end as BONUS_VAL,
 case when b.element_name = 'LTP' then trim(trailing '.' from to_char(a.value,'fm99D9')) else ' ' end as LTP_VAL,
 b.person_id as PERSON_ID
from b left join peevf a
on b.person_id = a.person_id
  and b.element_name = a.element_name
  and b.msd = a.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
;
```

### SQL2:

Select using a `max over by`. You can get rid of the `rowid` if the order of the result does not matter or if there is another order.

```
select 
  LATEST_EFF_DT_BONUS,
  LATEST_EFF_DT_LTP,
  BONUS_VAL,
  LTP_VAL,
  person_id
from (
 select
  case when element_name = 'Bonus' then to_char(EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') else ' ' end  as LATEST_EFF_DT_BONUS,
  case when element_name = 'LTP' then to_char(EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') else ' ' end as LATEST_EFF_DT_LTP,
  case when element_name = 'Bonus' then trim(trailing '.' from to_char(value,'fm99D9')) else ' ' end as BONUS_VAL,
  case when element_name = 'LTP' then trim(trailing '.' from to_char(value,'fm99D9')) else ' ' end as LTP_VAL,
  max(effective_end_date)    over ( PARTITION BY ELEMENT_NAME,PERSON_ID order by PERSON_ID) as mo,
  EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,
  rowid rn,
  person_id
 from peevf
) a
where
a.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE = a.mo
order by rn
;
```

### Output:

| LATEST_EFF_DT_BONUS | LATEST_EFF_DT_LTP | BONUS_VAL | LTP_VAL | PERSON_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11-APR-2022 |  | 12 |  | 19 |
|  | 19-APR-2022 |  | 9 | 19 |
| 01-JAN-2019 |  | 5 |  | 8 |
| 11-JAN-2021 |  | 11.1 |  | 10 |
|  | 11-APR-2019 |  | 9.8 | 1 |

### DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE PEEVF
    ("EFFECTIVE_START_DATE" timestamp, "EFFECTIVE_END_DATE" timestamp, "PERSON_ID" int, "ELEMENT_NAME" varchar2(5), "VALUE" number)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO PEEVF ("EFFECTIVE_START_DATE", "EFFECTIVE_END_DATE", "PERSON_ID", "ELEMENT_NAME", "VALUE")
         VALUES ('01-Jan-2021 12:00:00 AM', '10-Jan-2021 12:00:00 AM', 19, 'Bonus', 9.1)
    INTO PEEVF ("EFFECTIVE_START_DATE", "EFFECTIVE_END_DATE", "PERSON_ID", "ELEMENT_NAME", "VALUE")
         VALUES ('11-Jan-2021 12:00:00 AM', '28-Mar-2021 12:00:00 AM', 19, 'Bonus', 11)
    INTO PEEVF ("EFFECTIVE_START_DATE", "EFFECTIVE_END_DATE", "PERSON_ID", "ELEMENT_NAME", "VALUE")
         VALUES ('29-Mar-2021 12:00:00 AM', '10-Apr-2021 12:00:00 AM', 19, 'Bonus', 11.1)
    INTO PEEVF ("EFFECTIVE_START_DATE", "EFFECTIVE_END_DATE", "PERSON_ID", "ELEMENT_NAME", "VALUE")
         VALUES ('11-Apr-2021 12:00:00 AM', '31-Dec-2021 12:00:00 AM', 19, 'Bonus', 10)
    INTO PEEVF ("EFFECTIVE_START_DATE", "EFFECTIVE_END_DATE", "PERSON_ID", "ELEMENT_NAME", "VALUE")
         VALUES ('11-Apr-2022 12:00:00 AM', '30-Apr-2022 12:00:00 AM', 19, 'Bonus', 12)
    INTO PEEVF ("EFFECTIVE_START_DATE", "EFFECTIVE_END_DATE", "PERSON_ID", "ELEMENT_NAME", "VALUE")
         VALUES ('19-Apr-2022 12:00:00 AM', '30-May-2022 12:00:00 AM', 19, 'LTP', 09)
    INTO PEEVF ("EFFECTIVE_START_DATE", "EFFECTIVE_END_DATE", "PERSON_ID", "ELEMENT_NAME", "VALUE")
         VALUES ('01-Jan-2019 12:00:00 AM', '30-Apr-2019 12:00:00 AM', 8, 'Bonus', 5)
    INTO PEEVF ("EFFECTIVE_START_DATE", "EFFECTIVE_END_DATE", "PERSON_ID", "ELEMENT_NAME", "VALUE")
         VALUES ('11-Mar-2021 12:00:00 AM', '10-Jan-2021 12:00:00 AM', 10, 'Bonus', 11)
    INTO PEEVF ("EFFECTIVE_START_DATE", "EFFECTIVE_END_DATE", "PERSON_ID", "ELEMENT_NAME", "VALUE")
         VALUES ('11-Jan-2021 12:00:00 AM', '28-Mar-2021 12:00:00 AM', 10, 'Bonus', 11.1)
    INTO PEEVF ("EFFECTIVE_START_DATE", "EFFECTIVE_END_DATE", "PERSON_ID", "ELEMENT_NAME", "VALUE")
         VALUES ('20-Jan-2019 12:00:00 AM', '08-Mar-2019 12:00:00 AM', 1, 'LTP', 9)
    INTO PEEVF ("EFFECTIVE_START_DATE", "EFFECTIVE_END_DATE", "PERSON_ID", "ELEMENT_NAME", "VALUE")
         VALUES ('11-Apr-2019 12:00:00 AM', '19-Aug-2019 12:00:00 AM', 1, 'LTP', 9.8)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```